# Explicit tensorflow session gives fetch error in Tensorflow/nmt

Tags: tensorflow, opennmt

This kind of tf.session works fine:

```
with tf.Session(graph=self.infer_model.graph, config=utils.get_config_proto()) as sess:
          loaded_infer_model = model_helper.load_model(self.infer_model.model, self.ckpt, sess, "infer")
```

But I have to keep persistent session for reuse. So instead of creating tf.session by "with" statement, I created a under:

```
sess = tf.Session(
            graph=infer_model.graph, config=utils.get_config_proto())
loaded_infer_model = model_helper.load_model(
              infer_model.model, ckpt, sess, "infer")
```

But this gives following error (in model_helper.load_model ): Can someone please suggest for how to load explicit session which can be reused?

> File "/home/pksingh/sans/app/nmt/model_helper.py", line 444, in
>   load_model session.run(tf.tables_initializer()) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 889, in run run_metadata_ptr) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1103, in _run self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor,
>   feed_handles=feed_handles) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 414, in init self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 242, in for_fetch return _ElementFetchMapper(fetches,
>   contraction_fn) File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 278, in init 'Tensor. (%s)' % (fetch, str(e))) ValueError: Fetch
>   argument  cannot be
>   interpreted as a Tensor. (Operation name: "init_all_tables" op: "NoOp"
>   is not an element of this graph.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option to achieve the same is to use an interactive session. You can initialize an interactive session like this:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
```

Visit this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/InteractiveSession) for more details.